# Datagrid view getting more o loading datas

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

```
Am using datagrid in my windows application, its getting more time to load datas(13 Seconds for 65000 items)
```

am doing  Billing Appication for supermarket, i used searching directly from cell to list items in another grid on key down. i know keydown edit event not in Microsoft datadridview, so used to call key down in *_EditingControlShowing*.

```
 private void gvSalesItem_EditingControlShowing(object sender,DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Control.KeyDown -= new KeyEventHandler(Control_KeyDown);
        }

 private void Control_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F5)
            {

                LoadItems();//here is showing list of items in grid by data source
            }
        }
```

i think *flexgrid* can make it fix loading datas instantly, if not so Please Advice a solution.

**Thanks in Advance**

**Datagridview getting more time to load datas(13 Seconds for 65000 items)**

Comment: what does your binding code/sql query look like?

Comment: also do you need to have the ability for the user to edit the data, or is it just for display?

Comment: AM using sql, dont want to edit datas in current grid view, want to make a select items from it dats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a `DataSet` for your `SqlDataSource` `DataSourceMode`attribute or if you have not set the attribute the default is a `DataSet`. This loads all records returned by the query into memory into a `DataSet` object which automates paging, updating records, etc...

For performance if you use the `DataReader` option for your `DataSourceMode` or manually bind to a `SqlDataReader` you will get better performance in loading your data. Downside of this is that you will have to write your own paging/sorting logic and may have to alter your query to only give you the records you are displaying at a time instead of selecting all records from the database.

This may not be a viable solution for you, but it WILL improve the performance of loading your data.